# How to stop Futurebuilder inside of a Futter loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to stop a loop once Futurebuilder stops returning chips.
For my future builder, I receive back a list of strings, and I create a chip out of the index of that string is at, and then put that into a list I use later in my program.

```
extractFutureChip(_response, index){

return FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: _response, // if you mean this method well return image url
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {

                if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                  var jsonString = snapshot.data;
                  //print(jsonString);
                  List terms = jsonDecode(jsonString);
                  if(index>=terms.length){
                    return Container(height: 0.0,width: 0.0,);
                  }
                  //print(terms);
                  Chip return_val = Chip(

                    backgroundColor: Colors.orange[900],
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    label: Text(terms[index])
                  );
                    return return_val;

                }else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                  return Chip(

                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    label: Text("Loading")
                  );
                }
               return Chip(

                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    label: Text("ERROR")
                  );
              }
            );
}
```

I've tried throwing and catching an exception, but that didn't work,
I've tried if the type of object doesn't match, break out of a while loop.

The current working solution is just setting a high number of maximum chips, and then returning empty containers if the index exceeds the number of items in the future list.

```
while(true){
      if(ind>200){
        break;
      }
  var chip = extractFutureChip(tags2, ind);
      list_of_skills.add(chip);
      //print(list_of_skills);
      ind+=1; 
    }
```

But the two issues here are, what if someone has over 200 things,
And searching for a high number of things, when most of the responses will have less than 5 strings in them, is just really inefficient.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're trying to build the Chips bit by bit as opposed to building the entire list of chips once the whole Future is completed?

Comment: i think you should read carefully [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-async/Future-class.html) and [this](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Comment: @Wecherowski is there a way I can do the entire list? I thought future builders were only for a single widget

Comment: @pskink I've read both of those already,
neither really deal with future builders

Comment: you need `FutureBuilder` only for presenting your future data - and you need only one `FutureBuilder` not multiple - why do you want to store multiple `FutureBuilder`s in `list_of_skills` ? most likely `list_of_skills` should store `Future`s not `FutureBuilder`s

Comment: @pskink I need it to be a list of chip widgets that I can put into the program lower down on the screen and I'm not sure how to return a list of chips from future builder... I haven't been able to find that in examples or in any documentation that I could understand. I'm putting the list of chips in a "Wrap" widget.

Comment: something like: `child: FutureBuilder(
/* import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart' as words;
 var chips_data = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () => words.nouns.take(16)); */
  future: chips_data,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    var i = 0;
    return Wrap(
      spacing: 8,
      children: <Widget>[
     ...snapshot.data.map((n) => Chip(
       label: Text('${i++} $n'),
       backgroundColor: i.isOdd? Colors.black12 : Colors.black26,
          elevation: 4,
        ))
      ],
    );
  },
),`

Comment: @pskink it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you misunderstood the purpose of FutureBuilder a bit: 
1) `FutureBuilder` just updates your widget tree whenever the passed in future changes and 2) it's meant to return a Widget (tree). So the simplest way for you to build a list from the `_response` obj once it's ready would be with the [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget inside your method.

E.g.

```
return FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _response, // if you mean this method well return image url
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
      var jsonString = snapshot.data;
      List terms = jsonDecode(jsonString);

      return Wrap(
        children: List.generate(terms.length, (index) => Chip(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange[900],
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            label: Text(terms[index])
        )),
      );
    } else if (...) { ... }
    else return Container(); 
  });
```

If on the other hand you want to split up the asynchronous request to obtain the future data and the widget build, then you should probably use some kind of init function instead of a FutureBuilder:

```
Future<List<String>> someFunc() async {
  try {
    var jsonString = await _response;
    // do some more manipulation or other stuff
    return jsonDecode(jsonString);
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    // TODO you can catch exceptions coming from the Future here
  }
}
```

(and then build the chips with the returned list of strings)